# How do I extract a set of numbers from a QString that are after an space or before/after a bracket?

Tags: regex, qt, qstring

I'm new in QT and not that new in C++. and although I'm not that good of a programmer I try.
This time I can't figure a way to.

I'll be doing a QT application and I'll be having data in the form of

```
[1 2 45 345 98 452]
```

(It could be either that or `[1,2,45,345,98,452]`, don't know what will be easier)

and I need the numbers stored in an array
So i need to separate the 1 from the 2 from the 45 and so on, and also to know how many numbers there are.

Any ideas?
So far I've separated the numbers from the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way would be to use `QRegularExpression` with `\d+` and iterate over each number. Then you can save the result in a `QVector<int>`.

Note that `QRegExp` is deprecated in Qt 5+

```
QString number = "[1 2 45 345 98 452]";
QRegularExpression rx("\\d+");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(number);
QVector<int> vec1;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    vec1.append(match.captured(0).toInt());
}
qDebug() << vec1;
```

> Output QVector(1, 2, 45, 345, 98, 452)

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me what each part of the code does? I've been looking at the documentation but it is quite confusing. Thanks mate.

Comment: Memo Guerrero:  the code iterates over digits one-by-one in a string. `\d+` is the regex for digits only. Then the code writes the captured numbers in the vector. So you can access the numbers with `for(auto n : vec1) { qDebug() << n; }` or `qDebug() << vec1.at(index);`. The code works also with `[1,2,45,345,98,452]`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, just figured it out.
Look

```
QString myString ="[1 0 12 8 0 12 134]"; //Let's say in data
qDebug() << myString.count(QLatin1Char(' ')); //Counting how many spaces
int size = myString.count(); 
qDebug() << size;
QString newString = myString.mid(1,size-2); //My new string without the []


QRegExp sep("( |,|[|])"); //Regex thingy separating stuff
QStringList list = newString.split(sep);
qDebug() << list;  // TA DA!
```

Are there fancier ways to achieve this?
THANKS